# How can I put FragmentTabHost Tabs at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android

I have tried the following code. which aligns the framed layout above the tab widget but it still didn't work

```
 <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
             />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

**edit**
i am using FragmentTabHost. maybe that could be why it's not changing position

Comment: And I take it you've read the [Pure Android Design Guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html) and are purposefully ignoring the 'Don't use bottom tab bars' platform guideline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which finally worked for is the following:

```
  <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
        </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How may it look like ? please upload the screenshot.

Comment: Bummer. Changed the background color in order to be able to see it on the graphical UI builder in eclipse. And looked as if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: Bummer. Changed the background color in order to be able to see it on the graphical UI builder in eclipse. And looked as if it would work.