# How i put the android tabactivity at the bottom of activity?

Tags: android, tabactivity, android-tabactivity, tabview, uitabview

On default the tabactivity is in the top of the activity
How i put the android tabactivity at the bottom of activity ? (like ios tabview)

thanks a lot
by

Comment: many people will tell you not to do it. If you are doing something for people using android, well, they expect android behavior.

Comment: and then if you want to do it did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098366/how-can-i-put-fragmenttabhost-tabs-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen

Comment: it doesnt work but no problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```